# Inserting date as integer in oracle using python

Tags: python, oracle, datetime

I want to insert a date into oracle as integer using python. Below is my code.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy
import math
import time

def update_output_table_last_transaction(customer_id_list,column_name,column_value_list) :
num_rows_to_add = len(customer_id_list)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
c = conn.cursor()

for i in range(0,num_rows_to_add,1) :
    print type(column_value_list[i]) 
    print column_value_list[i]
    c.execute("""UPDATE output SET """+column_name+""" = %s WHERE customer_id = %s""" %(column_value_list[i].datetime.datetime.strftime('%y%m%d'),customer_id_list[i]))
    conn.commit()
print "Completed updating " + column_name

last_transaction_date_df = pd.read_sql("""select distinct b.customer_id, MAX(a.date_of_issue) as "LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE" from 
transaction_fact a inner join customer_dim b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id group by b.customer_id""",conn)

 update_output_table_last_transaction(list(last_transaction_date_df['CUSTOMER_ID']),'LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE',list(last_transaction_date_df['LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE']))
```

I ran above code, but it is giving me following error :
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'datetime' on line where date(as integer) being inserted into the database using 'strftime' method.

Please ignore if it's a silly doubt, I am a newbie.

Comment: Please check what type has column_value_list[i]. If you access it with "column_value_list[i].something" ist could be a namedtuple.

Comment: column_value_list[i] is a type of Timestamp.

Comment: Oh, of course, that's what you already mentioned above. Sorry. Can you please show us how the value in clumn_value_list[i] is generated? If you've got this value from "fromtimestamp()" then try dropping your "datetime.datetime." after "column_value_list[i].".

Comment: column_value_list contains the last transaction dates of each customer. It is in the form of list, so I am iterating over it and trying to insert date corresponding to customer.

Comment: What about my suggestion "drop datetime.datetime"?